# Obtain Virtual IP - Azure App Service Environment

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, azure-networking, virtual-ip, azure-web-apps

I am trying to setup **IP Based SSL** instead of **SNI SSL** on an azure Web App.

The App Service Plan is Standard S1, but unfortunately I am getting the following error message:
**There are no IP addresses in the App Service Environment that are available to be assigned to your app.**

What are the possible options?

I believe moving the current Web App to a different App Service Plan in a different resource group would solve this issue. I Have already tried moving the App service plan to a different resource group but failed.
[image: Clicking the button doesn't work]
*Note: Clicking the scale up button doesn't work and shows a JavaScript error in the console*

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the change via powershell 
Login-AzureRmAccount

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId aaaaaa-2f8e-4308-8cba-e1f8e8b90349

New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding -ResourceGroupName taxmanrg-rg -WebAppName taxmanwebapp -Thumbprint B205CBFA0FCF30A88CA20B0F50C94F8C8F3E6AC6 -Name www.taxman.com -SslState IpBasedEnabled